# How to run test files in Clojure

Tags: testing, clojure, jedit

I'm using jEdit and what I want to do is to write a file and run tests to it. I'm interested in the process of running the tests, not the files themselves.

So I wrote this simple function in `File.clj`

```
(defn abs [n]
  (if (neg? n) (- n) n))
```

And this test in `TheTest.clj`

```
(use 'clojure.test)

(load-file "File.clj")

(deftest sample-test
  (testing "abs"
    (is (= 5 (abs (5))))))

(run-tests)
```

and then I run the file `TheTest.clj` but it says:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: File.clj (The system cannot find the file specified) (TheTest.clj:49)`

Can someone please tell is this is the way to do the things, and if not how to run the tests :( It's not necessary to be in jEdit, it may be in the command prompt if it should. Also I have leiningen installed and `File.clj` and `TheTest.clj` are in same directory. I also tried providing the whole path to the file in the load-file function but with no success.

Thank you very much, good people! :)

Comment: Is it a leiningen project?

Comment: No, it's not. Is there a way to run the test without making a project?

Comment: Leiningen works with files inside its project. Just create Leiningen project and you will get complete toolkit, not just possibility to run tests. And if you just want to run some code to test your idea or something like this, run normal function.

Comment: Can you show how you have your namespaces set up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's certainly possible to get your example working without Leingingen. It works on my computer with one minor alteration: remove the brackets around `5`, so the test line reads

```
(is (= 5 (abs 5)))
```

To run the script successfully, find the location of your Clojure JAR, open a terminal and switch to the directory where your source files live, then execute the following:

```
java -cp /path/to/clojure/clojure-1.4.0.jar clojure.main TheTest.clj
```

Obviously replace `/path/to/clojure/clojure-1.4.0.jar` with the actual path to Clojure on your system. If you've used Leiningen at all there'll be a copy in your Maven repository (I've got it at `~/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.4.0/clojure-1.4.0.jar`)

I've run `TheTest.clj` and the output is:

```
Testing user

Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```